# Cannot edit ArcGIS data in an SQL Server enterprise geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase

I have created a geodatabase in SQL Server 14. I import some layers to the geodatabase and everything goes ok. I use ArcGIS 10.6.1 Advanced.

The problem is when I try to EDIT these layers. It doesn't let me and the following error appears:

> Not editable layers
>   The workspace containing this data cannot be edited.

What is the problem?

Comment: I bet that the user account that you are using doesn't have all the needed read/write rights to the tables. Here is a helpful link - https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/add-users-sqlserver.htm

Comment: Is this database versioned? What client software are using (e.g. ODBC )?

Comment: How did you create the geodatabase? Did you use the ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase tools?

Answer (score 0):

With an enterprise geodatabase, ArcGIS doesn't allow editing by default unless the feature class (or table) is versioned.

However, this is easy to change if you do not want to version your data...

1. In the **Editing toolbar** from the **'Editor' menu**, choose **'Options...'**.
2. In the **'Editing Options'** dialogue window, choose the **'Versioning' tab**.
3. **Deselect the option to 'Edit a version of the database with the ability to undo a redo.'**

Optionally (I always do this)...

- **Deselect the option to 'Automatically save changes after each edit.'**

NB:  This needs to be done for every MXD.  These settings are document specific, not application-wide.

Alternatively, the schema owner could enable versioning on the dataset(s) in question.  Enabling versioning, however, starts off a whole new ball game of complications is is way overkill for most situations.  If you really wanted to do it, the data owner can do this by:

- Right-click on the dataset
- Manage -> Register As Versioned...

But I would not recommend using versioning unless you REALLY need it.  It can create some significant data maintenance issues that you need to be on top of.

Of course, whichever of the above techniques you use, you also need to have editing (update/delete) privileges at the database level to the feature classes and tables that you want to edit.  If you do not, then the schema owner will need to grant you these privileges using the option:

- Right-click on the dataset
- Manage -> Privileges...

**UPDATE:**

Actually, the error message you have quoted is different to the error message I would expect to be resolved by the information in this answer.  The (not terribly helpful) ESRI documentation for that particular error message is at:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/the-workspace-containing-this-data-cannot-be-edited.htm

How did you create the geodatabase?  Did you use the ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase tools?